# Tint all UIBarButtonItems in my App (MFMailComposer, etc)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I created a custom Navbar for my application using a protocoll:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

[image]

this works fine. all toolbars in my application look great now. but i also want a way to tint my uibarbuttonitems in my toolbar. i could set the tint color of every button, but this does not work on pre-defined items like the ones in my mailcomposerview and so on.

is there a way to give all my buttons a tint color? just like i've done that with my navigation bar.

Comment: Until iOS 4.0 this was easy to achieve. Now it seems impossible. I am able to color nab bar buttons that aren't the highlighted default buttons. Will post code asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the tintColor for navigationBar property of your navigation controller.

Comment: for every navigationbar in my application? :O

Comment: You only have one for each navigation controller ;)

Comment: but how to do this for a MFMailComposer f.e.?

Comment: You probably mean MFMailComposeViewController. Same way, as MFMailComposeViewController inherits from UINavigationController:  myMailComposer.navigationBar.tintColor

Comment: sounds currently like the best solution. bad that there isn't a 'do it all with one line' - solution as for the navigationbars background itself ;)

Answer (score 1):

self.tintColor = whatever in your drawRect will do it